# Java Simple Client/Server read/write

Tags: java, client-server, bufferedreader, printwriter

I`m trying to make a Simple chat between the Client and Server or 2 way Communication

The Problems I`m facing is if I Keep Entering new text on any one side then that does not show up... only the first text Entered Shows up.

Both Server and Client side quit after a text has been Entered from server side once and once from client side.

```
Server
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Server {
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket s;
    InputStream input;
    OutputStream out;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;
    String str1;
    String str2;
    public void create() throws Exception{
       server=new ServerSocket(40000);
       System.out.println("Begin :) Server");
       s=server.accept();
       input=s.getInputStream();
       out=s.getOutputStream();
       br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
       pw=new PrintWriter(out);
       t1.start();
       t2.start();
    }
    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run (){
         str1=in.nextLine();
         pw.println(str1);
         pw.flush();
        }
    });
    Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
           try{
            str2=br.readLine();
           }catch(Exception e){}
           System.out.println(str2);
        }
    });
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       Server s=new Server();
       s.create();       
    }
}


Client
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Client {
    Socket s;
    InputStream input;
    OutputStream out;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;
    Scanner in;
    String str1;
    String str2;
    public void create() throws Exception{
        s=new Socket("localhost",40000);
        System.out.println("Begin :) Client");
        input=s.getInputStream();
        out=s.getOutputStream();
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        pw=new PrintWriter(out);
        in=new Scanner(System.in);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
             str1=in.nextLine();
             pw.println(str1);
             pw.flush();
        }
    });
    Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                str2=br.readLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {}   
            System.out.println(str2);
        }
    });
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client c=new Client();
        c.create();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve 2 way Communication without using threads?

Comment: You should wait for a message in an infinite loop, when you get a message *then* spawn a Thread to handle it.

Comment: Hi the threads t1 & t2 are always running and hence when a text is in the stream won`t they read it from the stream and print it? also even if main thread terminates the threads t1 & t2 should n`t terminate rite? so then why does after an entry each in server and client the whole programs terminates?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
    str1=in.nextLine();
    pw.println(str1);
    pw.flush();
}
```

did the same for all the other run method statements and the code runs fine